# Raspberry Pi3B USB ports not working

Tags: usb, usb-power

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B v1.2 2015 which always worked really fine.
But today I want to use it to read a serial comm from a BMS but the USB ports don't work.

There are 5 volts reaching the port, to power iPhone or mouse led. The Ethernet work great except for the USB communication. I was able to ssh through the ethernet port but no signal from a mouse or keyboard. They turn on lights but no moves.

My power supply offers 5v with 2.4A capacity, but it still alarming low power.

This is the error when I try to plug a USB thing on it:

```
[ 2468.716693] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 100 using dwc_otg
[ 2469.156694] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 100, error -32
[ 2469.476688] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 101 using dwc_otg
[ 2469.916697] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 101, error -32
[ 2469.916812] usb 1-1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 2470.216709] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 102 using dwc_otg
[ 2470.536710] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2470.976704] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2471.196713] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 103 using dwc_otg
[ 2471.516717] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2471.956714] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
```

Comment: Does the log represent the communication attempt with a USB mouse/keyboard? Did you check that the USB mouse/keyboard works when plugged into another computer?

Comment: Have you tried to see how much power the device is consuming? User `lsusb -v | egrep "^Bus|MaxPower"`

Comment: Yes, I did the troubleshooting like dmesg or lsusb, but nothing. There are 5v arriving in the USB ports but no connection.